# Storyboard designable issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, storyboard

I have created a project in which I am using one .a file (Static library) . In that .a file I have some views I want use them in Storyboard in my sample . If I link my view in Storyboard with that view it shows "**Designable error**" in Storyboard but Its working fine while running in simulator & device . 
For testing purpose I created one objective  view class with in my sample then I did same process then its working fine I can see my view design in Storyboard  .

So how to resolve this?